# Телеграм бот на aiogram не хочет запускаться на Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, aiogram, pycharm

Я пишу телеграм бота с использованием библиотеки aiogram. На Windows всё прекрасно — работает, запускается.
Но мне очень хочется поработать над этим проектом на своём ноутбуке (linux ubuntu 22.04). Я перенёс файлы бота через github на свой ноутбук. Всё было хорошо, пока я не запустил бота.

Проблема в том, что проблемы по всей видимости нет. Бот запускается и работает, как показывает PyCharm, однако при проверке через телеграм — бот ни на что не реагирует. Плюс при запуске бота с Windows — в консоли пишется:

> Updates were skipped successfully!

А запуская код с ноута этого сообщения нет.
Версия PyCharm 3.10.
Aiogram версии 2.25.1.

Comment: Включите логирование на уровне дебаг и посмотрите, что происходит

Comment: Не понял, можно подробнее?